# SQL add column to table base another column and row

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I create a table show the total revenue for year and month, I want to add a column to table show if the total revenue after is greater than 10 precents revenue before.

I tried:

```
select DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS OrderYear,
DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate) AS OrderMonth,
ROUND(SUM(UnitPrice*Quantity-Discount),2) AS Total_Revenue,
case when   SUM(UnitPrice*Quantity-Discount)  > 10 THEN '>10' ELSE '<=10' end  my_col
FROM [Order Details], Orders
WHERE Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate)
```

I got:

[image]

I need to get:

[image]

The problem is that I need to calculate the percentage of change between the previous row and the current row, how can I do that?

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assignment...?

Comment: This is a homework assignment, I tried but I didn't succeed.

Comment: This website is not for solving homework assignments.  You need to figure these things out on your own or you won't learn.  What help I will give you is to look into the `lag` and `lead` functions.

Comment: @iamdave the OP has actually shared their attempt here, so I would suggest this is on topic. The help page says *"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* They've shown us what they're tried, and the results they're after. You're right, what they are after is `LEAD` and `LAG`. Eliad, I suggest reading the documentation on `LAG` and showing your new attempt. If you don't understand the syntax, then add detail in your question about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG()`.  I would recommend a subquery, to simplify naming:

```
select ym.*,
       (case when Total_Revenue > 1.1 * lag(Total_Revenue) over (order by orderyear, ordermonth)
             then 'Reached'
             else 'Missed'
        end)
from (select DATEPART(YEAR, o.OrderDate) AS OrderYear,
             DATEPART(MONTH, o.OrderDate) AS OrderMonth,                
     ROUND(SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity - od.Discount), 2) AS Total_Revenue
      from [Order Details] od join
           Orders o
           on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
      group by DATEPART(YEAR, o.OrderDate), DATEPART(MONTH, o.OrderDate)
     ) ym
order by orderyear, ordermonth;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases, which are abbreviations for the table names.
- Qualify all column references, especially when your query references more than one table.